# How to decode data for JSON UTF encoding

Tags: php, json

I am working on an multilanguage application and we use utf8_genral_ci to store information in multilanguage.
information store correctly in database but json encoding give me data in improper formate.

these are what i am getting from server

```
{"Result":[{"id":"1","name":"\u0939\u093f\u0902\u0926\u0940","admin_id":"29","active":"yes","time":"2013-06-04 03:26:47"},{"id":"2","name":"\u4e2d\u570b\u7684","admin_id":"29","active":"yes","time":"2013-06-04 03:27:11"},{"id":"3","name":"fran\u00e7ais","admin_id":"29","active":"yes","time":"2013-06-04 03:27:34"}]}
```

while i want to convert/save result in these formate

```
{
"Result": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "हिंदी",
        "admin_id": "29",
        "active": "yes",
        "time": "2013-06-04 03:26:47"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "中國的",
        "admin_id": "29",
        "active": "yes",
        "time": "2013-06-04 03:27:11"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "français",
        "admin_id": "29",
        "active": "yes",
        "time": "2013-06-04 03:27:34"
    }
]
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks fine to me. It's just escape-encoded.

Comment: Now check again problam i have made some edit.

Comment: @SurajGupta `JSON` only works with `utf8` encoded data.

Comment: @SurajGupta consider changing the title to "JSON UTF encoding" or something similar, so that others can find it and use it more easily. It has nothing to do with ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of your string, the unicode is not encoded in the string as UTF8, but as its representation. That is, if I craft a static string, I use \u..., but the compiler sees that and creates UTF8. When you see \u... in a string received from a server, it means it has been created using \ \u... - the \ was escaped. My guess is that you need to process the strings, looking for \uxxxx, and replace those with the real UTF8 for that code point.

Comment: Actually, with json_decode it's not needed to do this as it decodes those escape sequences automatically.

Comment: @Evert this was originally tagged as iOS, which is where I saw it. Not a php guy so was unaware, this is obviously the way to decode it, so thanks for updating my answer.